# How is a+(read/append) different from a(append) in php

Tags: php, append, text-files

I am reading(and slowly trying) the ways to interact with a txt file in php.
I have already tried append and it adds data to the end of the txt file 
But how is a+ different from a

In w3schools it says:

a
    Append. Opens and writes to the end of the file or creates a new file if it doesn't exist

a+
    Read/Append. Preserves file content by writing to the end of the file

What does a+ do differently and what does it actually "Preserve"

Comment: Please don't replace the [PHP  manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) with [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: a you can only write*, a+ you can read and write EDIT:typo

Comment: Thank you Hamza. Point well taken. 
And thank you to the.... second guy as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `a` you can just append to the end of the file.

With `a+` you can read the file too, so you can move the file pointer using `fseek` and add content somewhere else inside the file.

Comment: So after (a)append after you have finished the append process you can do nothing else and have to exit.

But in (a+) you can keep the connection open and do other stuff after the append is over.

Is this right?

Comment: Well with (a) you can keep appending as long as you don't close the handle, and with (a+) you can append, and then move the file cursor and append again somewhere else, as long as you don't call fclose before you are finished

Comment: You can't add content somewhere else. All writes are done at the end of the file, even with `a+` mode. `fseek()` only affects reading.